# Kohana and jQuery WYSIWYG editor

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, kohana

Is anyone out there having issues with Kohana and the jQuery WYSIWYG plugin?

Specifically the [jwysiwyg](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/) one.

Answer (score 0):

I use this jQuery plugin with Kohana 2.x, but I didn't had any problems with it.

Do you have a specific problem with the plugin?

Tell us so we can help you.